# How to assign [A-Z] to values in multi-dimensional array Py2.7

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

**Context**

I have a list of numbers in an array, I want to append a letter to the value in the array depending on the number.

**Code**

```
numbers = [] 
numbers.append(9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
```

**Psuedo-Code**

I've tried something like this but got stuck it failed and just assigned [A-Z] to each letter

```
for x in numbers:
   x.join('[A-Z]')
```

I want to add A to 9, B to 8, etc...

How do I do this dynamically?

Comment: *Add 'A' to 9*? but how? you can't add an integer to string.

Comment: There's either a multi-dimensional array option or to create a dictionary; I've done the latter

Comment: So that's not adding. Please update your question with your desire output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `chr` to convert a number to a character with that ASCII value. Since `a`'s ASCII is `97`, adding 97 to the index in the list and converting it back to a character will give you an increasing series of characters. All that you're missing is some list comprehensions to put it all together:

```
result = [str(x[1]) + chr(97 + x[0]) for x in enumerate(numbers)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import string

numbers = list(range(9,0,-1))   # list of numbers from range (you could use range directly)

paired = list(zip (numbers,string.ascii_uppercase))
di     = dict(zip (numbers,string.ascii_uppercase))
di2    = dict(zip (string.ascii_uppercase, numbers))

print (paired) # these are tuples, numbers first

print(di)      # dictionary, number as key

print(di2)     # dictionary, alpha as key
```

Output:

```
[(9, 'A'), (8, 'B'), (7, 'C'), (6, 'D'), (5, 'E'), (4, 'F'), (3, 'G'), (2, 'H'), (1, 'I')]

{9: 'A', 8: 'B', 7: 'C', 6: 'D', 5: 'E', 4: 'F', 3: 'G', 2: 'H', 1: 'I'}

{'A': 9, 'B': 8, 'C': 7, 'D': 6, 'E': 5, 'F': 4, 'G': 3, 'H': 2, 'I': 1}
```

`string.ascii_uppercase` is a const that contains what its named after,
`zip` takes n iterables and matches them on indexes as pairs - shortest iterable wins, elements of longer ones are discarded.

Doku: [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [string](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right you want a multidimensional array that looks like:

```
[('A', 9), ('B', 8),  # ... ]
```

In that case [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is helpful and you can use [`string.ascii_uppercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase):

```
import string
letters_to_numbers = list(zip(string.ascii_uppercase, numbers))

# => [('A', 9), ('B', 8), ...]
```

One cool side effect of how `dict` works is we can pass this into `dict` and get what you would expect (`'A'` maps to `9`, etc.):

```
letters_to_numbers = dict(zip(string.ascii_uppercase, numbers))
# => {'A': 9, 'B', 8, ...}
```

Note that in your construction of `numbers` you don't need to use append you can just use a literal:

```
numbers = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

If your intent is that numbers is always a descending series like that, you should look at range:

```
numbers = list(range(9, 0, -1))  # = [9, 8, 7, ..., 1]
```